# Template function error in clang but not gcc

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

I've got the following code that has a template function that is not called at any point:

```
#include <exception>

class MyException : public std::exception {
protected:
        MyException( const char* name, const char* reason = nullptr ){
        }
};

template <typename T>
void doSomething( T& temp ){
        throw MyException( "reason" );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
}
```

When using g++, the code compiles just fine, however using clang the compilation fails with the following error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -o clang-test test.cpp
test.cpp:11:8: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'MyException'
        throw MyException( "reason" );
              ^
test.cpp:5:2: note: declared protected here
        MyException( const char* name, const char* reason = nullptr ){
        ^
1 error generated.
```

If I call the function `doSomething`, g++ will then fail with a similar error:

```
test.cpp:11:8: error: ‘MyException::MyException(const char*, const char*)’ is protected within this context
```

So it seems that g++ is not bothering to parse the template function if it is not called, while clang is.  Are both g++ and clang valid in this case(e.g. it is compiler-specific/undefined), or is one of these compilers not aligned with the specification?

Comment: I tried declaring `namespace foo { }`, then declaring a version of `MyException` in the namespace with a public constructor, then a function that calls `doSomething()`. gcc still errored. Just a data point.

Comment: I couldn't find any explicit statement in the standard as to whether access checks are done in the definition context or the instantiation context

Comment: The standard does require the compiler to parse the template (if you change it to `throw DoesntExist();` you must get a diagnostic). MSVC++ was famously non-compliant in this regard, it used to save the template as a sequence of tokens, and not do any parsing until the instantiation context (other than the bare minimum to know where the end of the template was).

Comment: According to examples in [temp.res]/8 (`may be diagnosed even if X::f is not instantiated`) and [temp.nondep]/1 (`this could be diagnosed either here or at the point of instantiation`), it seems to me that both implementations are valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++17 [temp.res]/8 says:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - (8.1) no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement  within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
> - [...]
> - (8.3) a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter
> - [...]
>
> Otherwise, no diagnostic shall be issued for a template for which a valid specialization can be generated.

I'm never too sure about template instantiation stuff, but I think your program falls foul of both 8.1 and 8.3.   Every instantiation of the template will be ill-formed due to the access check failing, and there are no valid specializations (i.e. no `T` which makes it valid).

So the program is ill-formed NDR and therefore neither compiler is bugged.

Comment: Note that [gcc bug#55361](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55361) is a request for enhancement about it.